# How to install a python package from source?

Tags: python, c++

I am trying to install the PyDaw library in python using `python setup.py build` but am getting the following errors:

```
daw/FlpModule.cpp(19): error C3646: 'initflp': unknown override specifier
daw/FlpModule.cpp(19): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
daw/FlpModule.cpp(19): error C2059: syntax error: '('
daw/FlpModule.cpp(27): error C2078: too many initializers
daw/FlpModule.cpp(41): error C2440: 'initializing': cannot convert from 'const char [4]' to 'Py_ssize_t'
daw/FlpModule.cpp(41): note: There is no context in which this conversion is possible
daw/FlpModule.cpp(41): error C2440: 'initializing': cannot convert from 'destructor' to 'printfunc'
daw/FlpModule.cpp(41): note: This conversion requires a reinterpret_cast, a C-style cast or function-style cast
daw/FlpModule.cpp(41): error C2440: 'initializing': cannot convert from 'getattrfunc' to 'setattrfunc'
daw/FlpModule.cpp(41): note: This conversion requires a reinterpret_cast, a C-style cast or function-style cast
daw/FlpModule.cpp(41): error C2440: 'initializing': cannot convert from 'setattrfunc' to 'PyAsyncMethods *'
daw/FlpModule.cpp(41): note: There is no context in which this conversion is possible
daw/FlpModule.cpp(205): error C3861: 'Py_FindMethod': identifier not found
daw/FlpModule.cpp(264): error C3646: 'initflp': unknown override specifier
daw/FlpModule.cpp(264): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
daw/FlpModule.cpp(264): error C2084: function 'int DL_EXPORT(void)' already has a body
daw/FlpModule.cpp(19): note: see previous definition of 'DL_EXPORT'
daw/FlpModule.cpp(264): error C2059: syntax error: '('
daw/FlpModule.cpp(265): error C2143: syntax error: missing ';' before '{'
daw/FlpModule.cpp(265): error C2447: '{': missing function header (old-style formal list?)
error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2017\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.16.27023\\bin\\HostX86\\x86\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2
```

How can I get this working? I have tried both 32 and 64 bit versions of python but still same error.

Comment: Looks like you also authored [this issue](https://github.com/andrewrk/PyDaw/issues/2) on this package's repo; the additional information there that you did not include in this question mentions a missing `Python.h` file means your compiler could not find the Python header files.  You may wish to consult [documentation relevant to this compiler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/python/working-with-c-cpp-python-in-visual-studio?view=vs-2019).

Comment: @metatoaster I will be updating that issue as I already followed that documentation and I'm not getting the python header file error anymore which is why I didn't include it here.,